# Why is my city now attacking as a catapult?

Tags: civilization-5

I'm playing Civilization 5 and, out of a sudden, my city started to attack as a catapult. It used to throw arrows, now it throws rocks. What did I do?

Comment: Did your research efforts unlock Mathematics (which gives you the Catapult unit)...?

Answer (score 14):

The technologies in Civ 5 are broken up into various eras.  The first time you research a technology from a new era, you'll see some graphics update.  This means that the city will change in appearance in accordance to that era and the city long range attack with it.